# ResourceBundle file outside jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration

I have a spring boot application with `/resources/application.properties`, when deployed there is a `application.properties` next to the jar (and the one inside it).

Somewhere in the code I use `ResourceBundle.getBundle("application").getString("x")` but that always return the value defined in the properties inside the jar.

My objective is to get the value from the external file if it exists, if not then I need to get the value from inside the jar. Just like the default springs behavior but I'm not able to achieve this.

edit:

You can either use the solution in the correct answer below or you can rely on springs `Environment` by autowiring it and using `getProperty()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ResourceBundle.getBundle(String baseName)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle-java.lang.String-) relies on the classloader and not directly the file system to find the resource.
This is equivalent to invoke the overloaded one :

```
getBundle(baseName, Locale.getDefault(), this.getClass().getClassLoader()),
```

So your result is expected.
What you look for is [`PropertyResourceBundle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html).
To create an instance of you need either a `Reader` or an `InputStream`.

You could load both external and internal files.

```
ResourceBundle internalProps = ResourceBundle.getBundle("application");
ResourceBundle externalProps = new  PropertyResourceBundle(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("application.properties"));
```

You could so use the external `ResourceBundle` in first intention and the second one as fallback.